# If $a|b$ and $c|d$ then $ac|bd$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

If $a|b$ and $c|d$ then $ac|bd$.

Now $aq=b$ and $cr=d$. So multiply both equations we get result. Is this correct ?

Comment: @bill it says right there what was tried. The question is "is this [what I tried] correct?"

Comment: @MJD My main question was about $c$ and $d$ (but the post has since been edited which is all for the best). My subsequent question was only to try and better understand the context.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you mean

> If $a\mid b$ and $c\mid d$ then $ac\mid bd$.

And yes your proof is correct.

Alternatively, we have that $$\frac{bd}{ac}=\frac ba\cdot\frac dc$$ which is an integer since it is the product of two integers.